# Programmatically create a Range VSTO C#

Tags: c#, excel, range, vsto

Is it possible to way to create a **new** range inside of C# VSTO for Excel and specify rows/columns? I'm looking to make an abstract Range not related to any open sheets that I can manipulate and then insert into an arbitrary sheet.

This is **not** getting a range from an open spread sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. Office applications' object models differ from the kinds of "objects" .NET developers are accustomed to working with. It's only possible to create objects within the host "container" (Excel workbook, for example). Objects can't be created and manipulated "in memory".